# Simple jQuery function to collapse a div when another is clicked isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not looking for accordion functionality, but the ability to toggle multiple states when a single element is clicked. I thought this would be extremely simple, and it is. The code simply isn't working. Can anybody take a look at the code and suggest something I might try?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav_header").click(function(){
        if (desktopNavigation === 0) {
            $("#navigation").css("overflow","hidden");
            $("#navigation").css("height","0px");
            desktopNavigation = 1;
        }
        else if (desktopNavigation === 1) {
            $("#navigation").css("overflow","visible");
            $("#navigation").css("height","auto");
            desktopNavigation = 0;
        }
        else {
        }
    });
});
```

The initial value for the variable is as follows:

```
var desktopNavigation = 0;
```

The HTML I am trying to effect is in a page with jQuery loaded, and is as follows:

```
<div id="nav_header" class="trigger">
  <ul>
    <li>NAV MENU #1 Title</li>
    <li>NAV MENU #2 title</li>
    <li>NAV MENU #3 title</li>
    <li>NAV MENU #4 title</li>
    <li>NAV MENU #5 title</li>
  </ul>
</div><!--close nav_header-->
<div id="navigation" class="target" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="nav_column">
    NAV MENU #1
  </div><!--close nav_column-->
  <div id="nav_column">
    NAV MENU #2
  </div><!--close nav_column-->
  <div id="nav_column">
    NAV MENU #3
  </div><!--close nav_column-->
  <div id="nav_column">
    NAV MENU #4
  </div><!--close nav_column-->
  <div id="nav_column">
    NAV MENU #5
  </div><!--close nav_column-->
</div><!--close navigation-->
```

It may also be pertinent that I am executing this code on a wordpress page, and that it worked perfectly on my local environment.

Comment: what is `desktopNavigation` initially?

Comment: where have you declared `desktopNavigation` ?

Comment: @briansol Why change it?

Comment: `== 0` would also return true since undefined is the same as `== 0`, the double quotes allow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is lacking context.  What does "the code simply isn't working" mean?  Where is "desktopNavigation" define?  What exactly does "toggle multiple states" mean?

Going off assumptions, people can't give a direct, concise, answers.  With that being said, here is an example which hopefully answers your question:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seibert_cody/mk6juczp/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="nav_header"></div>    
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>I</li>
        <li>Am</li>
        <li>Iron</li>
        <li>Man</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var state = 0;
    var navClassMap = ["red_state", "blue_state", "green_state", "hidden_state"];

    // Each click will increment the class of the UL thus toggling multiple states
    $("#nav_header").click(function(){
        var $navigation = $("#navigation");  

        // remove the current class
        var curClass = navClassMap[state];
        $navigation.removeClass(curClass);    

        // Increment to the next class (loop back to start on overflow)
        state = (state + 1) % navClassMap.length;

        // Add the new class
        var nextClass = navClassMap[state];
        $navigation.addClass(nextClass);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#nav_header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ef102f;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav_header:hover{
    background-color: #Ff402f;
}

.red_state{
    color: red;
}

.blue_state{
    color: blue;    
}

.green_state{
    color: green;    
}

.hidden_state{
     display: none;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From within the code you provided its not clear what the var `desktopNavigation` initially is, so it will never be `=== 0`or `1`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var desktopNavigation = desktopNavigation || 0;

  $("#nav_header").click(function(){

    if (desktopNavigation === 0) {
        $("#navigation").css("overflow","hidden");
        $("#navigation").css("height","0px");
        desktopNavigation = 1;
    }
    else if (desktopNavigation === 1) {
            $("#navigation").css("overflow","visible");
        $("#navigation").css("height","auto");
        desktopNavigation = 0;
    }
    else {

    }
  });
});
```

or write:

```
...
if (desktopNavigation === 0 || !desktopNavigation) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Above your click function, add:

```
var desktopNavigation = 0;
```

Comment: Tries should stay in the comments.

Comment: It was a figure of speech. Gone now.

Answer (score 0):

`desktopNavigation` is probably undefined.

But if your goal is to hide a `div` may I suggest using the built in jQuery function `.toggle()`

```
$("#navigation").toggle();
```

Or if you want to toggle multiple, more extensive styles use `.toggleClass()` to add or remove a custom class.

```
$("#navigation").toggleClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

By "local environment", do you mean you have a wordpress environment set up on your local machine?  If the changes are working on your local and not on your remote, I would try:

- **Clearing your browser's cache** and **refresh the remote environment**
- **Inspecting the #navigation** element using chrome "inspect element" and make sure it **doesn't contain any extra css which may be hiding the #navigation**
- **Print to the console when the #nav_header is clicked**; this is to make sure the click callback is working as intended
- Check to make sure there isn't another element consuming the click which is wrapping #nav_header

One thing I will also note is that you define **id="nav_column"** multiple times; you shouldn't be using more than one instance of the same ID.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, they're all viable and work just fine. The problem was with Jquery itself.

This must have been a Wordpress thing, but when I changed the version of Jquery that enqueued, everything worked. It worked on my computer outside of wordpress, but as soon as I put it up live, none of the Jquery functions worked.

I changed it from 1.2.1 to 1.11.0. I thought it would be backward-compatible, but it seems like I have a lot to learn about Jquery.